# Graphics2D drawString() different colour

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I have this `Graphics2D g` object. Currently it renders a blue rectangle. What i would like is to be able to put a label in this rectangle, but seeing as the `g.setPaint(Color.BLUE)` sets the entire colour, any text rendered with `g.drawString(..)` is also blue and cannot be seen in the square. So for now "foo" sits next to the rectangle, how can i make it a different colour o that i can put it in the rectangle?

(All of the rectangles need to have a label)

[image]

i have considered making a copy of Graphics2D object, and have it render in the same way but with text only. Only thing is im not sure how to clone a Graphics2D object. Any insights?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> but seeing as the g.setPaint(Color.BLUE) sets the entire colour,

Don't use `setPaint(...)`

You can use `setColor(...)`:

```
g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
g.fillRect(...);
g.setColor( Color.WHITE );
g.drawString(...);
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply set the colors as you need them set when you need to set them.

```
g2d.setColor(BAR_COLOR);
g2d.fill(bar);
g2d.setColor(TEXT_COLOR);
g2d.drawString(....);
```

This will likely be within a for loop I imagine.

Answer (score 4):

Simply set the color, using the `.setColor(Color c)` method.

```
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```